# Can't connect to mongoDB with lithium

Tags: php, mongodb, lithium

I have uncomented mongodb connection in bootstrap/connections.php and everything seems to be ok but now I'm getting following error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'lithium\core\NetworkException' with message 'Could not connect to the database.' in C:\wamp\www\libraries\lithium\data\source\MongoDb.php on line 792
    ( ! ) lithium\core\NetworkException: Could not connect to the database. in C:\wamp\www\libraries\lithium\data\source\MongoDb.php on line 792
    Call Stack
    #   Time    Memory  Function    Location
    1   0.0004  370296  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
    2   0.0328  2618640 lithium\action\Dispatcher::run( )   ..\index.php:36
    3   0.0328  2619848 lithium\core\StaticObject::_filter( )   ..\Dispatcher.php:122
    4   0.0329  2621472 lithium\util\collection\Filters::run( ) ..\StaticObject.php:128
    5   0.0330  2623800 {closure}( )    ..\Filters.php:182
    6   0.0397  2692456 lithium\util\collection\Filters->next( )    ..\cache.php:47
    7   0.0397  2692488 {closure}( )    ..\Filters.php:201
    8   0.0428  2720784 lithium\util\collection\Filters->next( )    ..\action.php:52
    9   0.0428  2720816 lithium\action\{closure}( ) ..\Filters.php:201
    10  0.0448  2756432 lithium\core\StaticObject::invokeMethod( )  ..\Dispatcher.php:121
    11  0.0448  2756464 lithium\action\Dispatcher::_call( ) ..\StaticObject.php:74
    12  0.0449  2757552 lithium\core\StaticObject::_filter( )   ..\Dispatcher.php:203
    13  0.0449  2757808 lithium\action\{closure}( ) ..\StaticObject.php:121
    14  0.0449  2757808 lithium\action\Controller->__invoke( )  ..\Dispatcher.php:200
    15  0.0449  2759408 lithium\core\Object->_filter( ) ..\Controller.php:184
    16  0.0449  2759688 lithium\action\{closure}( ) ..\Object.php:245
    17  0.0450  2759936 lithium\core\Object->invokeMethod( )    ..\Controller.php:172
    18  0.0450  2759968 app\controllers\PostsController->add( ) ..\Object.php:167
    19  0.0643  3862976 lithium\data\entity\Document->save( )   ..\PostsController.php:25
    20  0.0643  3863176 lithium\data\Entity->__call( )  ..\Entity.php:0
    21  0.0644  3863672 call_user_func_array ( )    ..\Entity.php:197
    22  0.0644  3863936 lithium\data\Model->save( ) ..\Entity.php:0
    23  0.0644  3867352 lithium\data\Model::_filter( )  ..\Model.php:719
    24  0.0645  3867608 lithium\core\StaticObject::_filter( )   ..\Model.php:891
    25  0.0645  3867728 lithium\data\{closure}( )   ..\StaticObject.php:121
    26  0.0723  4182168 lithium\data\source\MongoDb->create( )  ..\Model.php:713
    27  0.0723  4182168 lithium\data\source\MongoDb->_checkConnection( )    ..\MongoDb.php:346
```

Seems kinda weird issue for me. To be exact was following lithium blog tutorial.

**EDIT adding mongo db configuration from phpinfo()**

```
mongo
MongoDB Support enabled
Version     1.1.3

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mongo.allow_empty_keys  0   0
mongo.allow_persistent  1   1
mongo.auto_reconnect    1   1
mongo.chunk_size    262144  262144
mongo.cmd   $   $
mongo.default_host  localhost   localhost
mongo.default_port  27017   27017
mongo.long_as_object    0   0
mongo.native_long   0   0
mongo.no_id 0   0
mongo.utf8  1   1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're running the latest Git master of Lithium. The last release version was 0.9.9, and the Mongo PECL extension has made 3 major BC-breaking changes since then. They're fixed in the core, they just haven't been rolled into a release yet. Also, a user name and password are NOT mandatory.

Comment: got it working by adding persistent => 'foo' to string but will try to get latest master to. Also nate when you expecting to release 1.0.0 ???

Comment: Soon. We just have a couple more features to go before the API goes stable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have correct host, port and login info make sure you have the newest version on MongoDb extension.

I had similar problem. Li3 uses `mongodb://{$login}{$host}/{$cfg['database']}` which wasn't supported by the older versions.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's this ticket (solved it for me):

http://rad-dev.org/lithium/tickets/view/204

Comment: actually it seems that to connect to MongoDB username and password is mandatory. Very strange

Comment: for me it had nothing to do with the username/password (i am not sure whether or not I have set a pass), but with the `persistant` flag, which I had to set to `somevalue` (false didn't work)

Comment: actually your ticket helped me added to connection array 'persistent'=>'foo' now it connects to mongo

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade my PECL extension to get it working.